# Pandas dataframe float index not self-consistent

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I need/want to work with float indices in pandas but I get a keyerror when running something like this:

```
inds = [1.1, 2.2]
cols = [5.4, 6.7]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 2), index=inds, columns=cols)
df[df.index[0]]
```

I have seen some errors regarding precision, but shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `KeyError` because `df[df.index[0]]` would try to access a column with label `1.1` in this case - which does not exist here.

What you can do is use `loc` or `iloc` to access rows based on indices:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

inds = [1.1, 2.2]
cols = [5.4, 6.7]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 2), index=inds, columns=cols)

# to access e.g. the first row use
df.loc[df.index[0]]
# or more general
df.iloc[0]

# 5.4    1.531411
# 6.7   -0.341232
# Name: 1.1, dtype: float64
```

In principle, if you can, avoid [equal comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python) for floating point numbers for the reason you already came across: precision. The `1.1` displayed to you might be `!= 1.1` for the computer - simply because that would theoretically require infinite precision. Most of the time, it will work though because certain tolerance checks will kick in; for example if the difference of the compared numbers is < 10^6.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear explanation. I see now it is a silly mistake but, being new to pandas, I couldn't see it!

Comment: @j_bio: glad I could help! And you *have* to do float comparisons, besides the SO post I linked there's also [numpy.isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) - just in case ;-)